# Python web programming with standard library

Tags: python, cgi, standard-library

I want to write a simple python web application to provide a gui to a command line program (think of `hg serve`, for example). It would run locally only. I don't want it to have any external dependencies for an easier deployment, so [python web programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209092/python-web-programming) in general wouldn't apply here

How can it be done with a minimal hassle?  Any pointer how to do it easily with `cgi` or `wsgi`, `string.Template` or `string.Formatter`? I'd prefer a Python 2.6 solution, but even a Python 3.x one is OK. I'd also prefer using a few html templates to manually assembling html together.

UPDATE:
The ideal solution would include ways

- to process a form
- to upload/download a file
- to output html
- to start a webserver

Comment: "simple python web application" and "I don't want it to have any external dependencies" are completely incompatible. Indeed, their diametric opposites.  You can't have both.  Which is more important?  Simple or no dependencies?  You can only choose one.

Comment: @S.Lott - As Steven pointed out in his answer, using a micro-framework can make this task easy while adding only a small dependency (a single file in the case of Bottle). This approach seems like a good balance between the two "diametric opposites".

Comment: @Adam Schmideg: Adding a dependency clearly violates "I don't want it to have any external dependencies".  It's not a "middle ground".   It's a perfectly sensible and logical solution.  It's highly recommended.  But it absolutely is not a "middle ground".  It absolutely and completely violates "I don't want it to have any external dependencies".  I did upvote that answer.  However, the question itself is so badly written that the question completely prevents **all** answers.

Comment: @S.Lott - When I was writing the question, I thought it to be black-and-white, either no dependency at all, or depending on a huge library. I can see now it's more fine-grained. Sorry if my bad writing prevented you answering. Luckily, I got a useful answer, Steven could sense my intention behind by words.

Comment: @S.Lott - How would you improve my question?

Comment: @Adam Schmideg: "How would you improve my question?"  What?  Are you unable to read the comments?  I'll repeat the issue, in case you missed it.  ""simple python web application" and "I don't want it to have any external dependencies" are completely incompatible. Indeed, they're diametric opposites."  If you want to improve your question, you cannot ask for diametric opposites and say that both are required.  You have to **prioritize** your requirements.  All features that you dream of are not equal.  Some are important, some are not important.  Prioritize.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [wsgiref](http://docs.python.org/library/wsgiref.html) package from the standard library has a simple server to serve wsgi applications. You can use it to run your own framework-less wsgi application, a minimal wsgi application isn't terribly difficult (see the hello world example at the end of the wsgiref documentation page)

You might want to relax the "standard library" requirement a little. You're going to have "dependencies" on your own modules anyway, is it really that bad to use something where someone else has already done the work?  Some of the so-called "microframeworks" shouldn't be too much of a problem for deployment. [Bottle](http://bottle.paws.de/docs/dev/index.html#) for example, comes as a single file module and has no dependencies other than stdlib (haven't used Bottle yet myself, but I picked that one as an example mainly because of the single file/no dependencies)

Comment: +1 you made me reconsider my original requirement.  Thanks for the microframework pointer. Bottle looks interesting.

Comment: I can certainly recommend Bottle. I have been using it for exactly the scenario described in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like SimpleHTTPServer?
http://docs.python.org/library/simplehttpserver.html#module-SimpleHTTPServer

Comment: Well, it's part of what I'm looking for, please, see the update to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/TwistedProject) is the way to go? Or do you consider this to be too much of an external dependency?

Comment: There are dozens of wonderful python web frameworks, I know. This question is about NOT using any of them, including twisted.